# WiFi failure in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom

My WiFi connection's been working fine for months and suddenly conked out. It's not the WiFi itself, as my phone and other machines can use it fine. It's my computer that can't connect to it (nor to any other WiFi networks previously used).

I figure it's something to do with the Broadcom drivers, but trying re-installs and purges and fresh installs of b43-firmware and similar things voted as best answers in other questions hasn't helped. At this point I've removed, installed, and re-installed a bunch of things so I don't know what exactly's going on.

Going to System > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers shows "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)"

Here's my Wireless Info Script output. I'm currently connected using a wired (ethernet?) connection.

> #### wireless info START
>
> Report from: 26 Jan 2016 17:25 EST -0500
>
> Booted last: 26 Jan 2016 16:53 EST -0500
>
> Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000
>
> release
>
> Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
>   Description:   Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
>   Release:   14.04
>   Codename:  trusty
>
> kernel
>
> Linux 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
>
> desktop
>
> Ubuntu
>
> lspci
>
> 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
>     Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0607]
>
> 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
>     Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2219]
>     Kernel driver in use: r8169
>
> lsusb
>
> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:700b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21f3 Broadcom Corp. 
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> PCMCIA card info
>   
>   rfkill
>
> 0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
>     Soft blocked: yes
>     Hard blocked: no
>   2: hci0: Bluetooth
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>
> lsmod
>
> brcmutil               15618  0 
>   mac80211              630728  0 
>   cfg80211              484040  1 mac80211
>   wmi                    19177  0
>
> interfaces
>
> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> ifconfig
>
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
>            inet addr:10.0.0.55  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>            inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
>            inet6 addr: 2601:41:4200:478b:/64 Scope:Global
>            inet6 addr: 2601:41:4200:478b:4939:9837:89b1:61f8/64 Scope:Global
>            inet6 addr: 2601:41:4200:478b::8f14/128 Scope:Global
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>            RX packets:186174 errors:3 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:3
>            TX packets:109429 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>            RX bytes:222693024 (222.6 MB)  TX bytes:12469299 (12.4 MB)
>
> iwconfig
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> route
>
> Kernel IP routing table
>   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>   10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
>
> resolv.conf
>
> nameserver 75.75.75.75
>   nameserver 75.75.76.76
>   nameserver 127.0.1.1
>   search hsd1.pa.comcast.net
>
> network managers
>
> Installed:
>
> NetworkManager
>
> Running:
>
> root      2555     1  0 06:53 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager
>
> NetworkManager info
>
> NetworkManager Tool
>
> State: connected (global)
>
> - Device: eth0  [Ifupdown (eth0)] ----------------------------------------------
>     Type:              Wired
>     Driver:            r8169
>     State:             connected
>     Default:           yes
>     HW Address:
>
>   Capabilities:
>     Carrier Detect:  yes
>     Speed:           1000 Mb/s
>
>   Wired Properties
>     Carrier:         on
>
>   IPv4 Settings:
>     Address:         10.0.0.55
>     Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
>     Gateway:         10.0.0.1
>
>   DNS:             75.75.75.75
>     DNS:             75.75.76.76
>
>   IPv6 Settings:
>     Address:         2601:41:4200:478b::8f14
>     Prefix:          128
>     Gateway:         fe80::bcd1:65ff:fe8c:8b68
>
>   Address:         2601:41:4200:478b:4939:9837:89b1:61f8
>     Prefix:          64
>     Gateway:         fe80::bcd1:65ff:fe8c:8b68
>
>   Address:         2601:41:4200:478b:
>     Prefix:          64
>     Gateway:         fe80::bcd1:65ff:fe8c:8b68
>
>   Address:         fe80::
>     Prefix:          64
>     Gateway:         fe80::bcd1:65ff:fe8c:8b68
>
>   Address:         2601:41:4200:478b::8f14
>     Prefix:          128
>     Gateway:         ::
>
>   DNS:             2001:558:feed::1
>     DNS:             2001:558:feed::2
>
> NetworkManager.state
>
> [main]
>   NetworkingEnabled=true
>   WirelessEnabled=true
>   WWANEnabled=true
>   WimaxEnabled=true
>
> NetworkManager.conf
>
> [main]
>   plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
>   dns=dnsmasq
>
> [ifupdown]
>   managed=true
>
> NetworkManager profiles
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/hhonors]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=hhonors | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=hhonors | mac-address=
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOME-8B65-5]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=HOME-8B65-5 | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=HOME-8B65-5 | mac-address=
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MIFI-LIBERATE-VA97]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=MIFI-LIBERATE-VA97 | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=MIFI-LIBERATE-VA97 | mac-address=
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AirPennNet]] (600 root)
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>   [connection] id=AirPennNet | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=AirPennNet
>   [802-1x] ca-cert=/home/matthew/.certificates/Student-CA.pem
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IM ON A BUFFALOOO]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=Network | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=Network | mac-address=
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AirPennNet-Help]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=AirPennNet-Help | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=AirPennNet-Help | mac-address=
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/M-Network]] (600 root)
>   [connection] id=M-Network | type=802-11-wireless
>   [802-11-wireless] ssid=M-Network | mac-address=
>   [ipv4] method=auto
>   [ipv6] method=auto
>
> iw reg get
>
> Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)
>
> country 00:
>     (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
>     (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
>     (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
>     (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
>     (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
>
> iwlist channels
>
> eth0      no frequency information.
>
> lo        no frequency information.
>
> iwlist scan
>
> eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
>
> lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
>
> module infos
>
> [brcmutil]
>   filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
>   license:        Dual BSD/GPL
>   description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
>   author:         Broadcom Corporation
>   srcversion:     E81EE4CBB6A7A689150D93D
>   depends:
>   intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
>   signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
>   sig_key:        45:B8:6D:4B:28:3F:CA:04:40:EC:04:F3:A7:A2:BC:67:5B:F4:69:44
>   sig_hashalgo:   sha512
>
> [mac80211]
>   filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
>   license:        GPL
>   description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
>   srcversion:     CD516ABEC909374CB2C52DC
>   depends:        cfg80211
>   intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
>   signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
>   sig_key:        45:B8:6D:4B:28:3F:CA:04:40:EC:04:F3:A7:A2:BC:67:5B:F4:69:44
>   sig_hashalgo:   sha512
>   parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
>   parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
>   parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
>   parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
>   parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)
>
> [cfg80211]
>   filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
>   description:    wireless configuration support
>   license:        GPL
>   author:         Johannes Berg
>   srcversion:     695424C2F5CD23A91B67E25
>   depends:
>   intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
>   signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
>   sig_key:        45:B8:6D:4B:28:3F:CA:04:40:EC:04:F3:A7:A2:BC:67:5B:F4:69:44
>   sig_hashalgo:   sha512
>   parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
>   parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)
>
> module parameters
>
> [mac80211]
>   beacon_loss_count: 7
>   ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
>   max_nullfunc_tries: 2
>   max_probe_tries: 5
>   probe_wait_ms: 500
>
> [cfg80211]
>   cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
>   ieee80211_regdom: 00
>
> /etc/modules
>
> lp
>   rtc
>
> modprobe options
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
>   blacklist ath_pci
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
>   blacklist b43
>   blacklist b43legacy
>   blacklist ssb
>   blacklist bcm43xx
>   blacklist brcm80211
>   blacklist brcmfmac
>   blacklist brcmsmac
>   blacklist bcma
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
>   blacklist evbug
>   blacklist usbmouse
>   blacklist usbkbd
>   blacklist eepro100
>   blacklist de4x5
>   blacklist eth1394
>   blacklist snd_intel8x0m
>   blacklist snd_aw2
>   blacklist i2c_i801
>   blacklist prism54
>   blacklist garmin_gps
>   blacklist asus_acpi
>   blacklist snd_pcsp
>   blacklist pcspkr
>   blacklist amd76x_edac
>   blacklist eth1
>   blacklist eth1_cs
>   blacklist lo
>   blacklist lo1_cs
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
>   alias net-pf-3 off
>   alias net-pf-6 off
>   alias net-pf-9 off
>   alias net-pf-11 off
>   alias net-pf-12 off
>   alias net-pf-19 off
>   alias net-pf-21 off
>   alias net-pf-36 off
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
>   remove iwlwifi \
>   (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
>   && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
>   softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
>
> rc.local
>
> exit 0
>
> pm-utils
>   
>   udev rules
>
> [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
>
> ## PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
>
> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
>
> ## PCI device 0x14e4:0x4359 (wl)
>
> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
>
> dmesg
>
> [  513.278974] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 654 at /build/linux-FE4z5Q/linux-3.13.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:1092 _request_firmware+0x5f9/0xb20()
>   [  513.279041] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_core videodev snd_hda_codec_realtek amd_freq_sensitivity snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_intel thinkpad_acpi nvram snd_hda_codec joydev snd_hwdep fam15h_power serio_raw k10temp edac_core snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm edac_mce_amd bcma rtsx_pci_ms memstick i2c_piix4 snd_rawmidi snd_page_alloc parport_pc snd_seq shpchp snd_seq_device ppdev snd_timer snd lp parport soundcore mac_hid dm_crypt crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel radeon aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit ttm psmouse drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci rtsx_pci mii wmi video
>   [  513.279103]  [] _request_firmware+0x5f9/0xb20
>   [  513.279107]  [] request_firmware+0x34/0x50
>   [  513.279181] usb 3-2: firmware: fw-0a5c_21f3.hcd will not be loaded
>   [  513.279185] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
>   [  513.358256] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:01:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
>   [  514.082628] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
>   [  514.082742] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
>   [  546.902379] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
>   [  546.902409] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
>
> #### wireless info END

Let me know if anything more would help.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**: Per commented request,

> sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl

returns

> modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

which I'm guessing means something...

**EDIT 2**:  Per answer,

> sudo apt-get update

Printed a bunch of stuff but appeared to throw no errors. However,

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

ran into an issue with wl again. Here's the output:

> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>    bcmwl-kernel-source
>   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0 B/1,512 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 8,038 kB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
>   (Reading database ... 413219 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom- 0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
>   Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
>   Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
>   First Installation: checking all kernels...
>   Building only for 3.13.0-68-generic
>   Building for architecture x86_64
>   Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the  kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
>   modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
>   update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
>   Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
>   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic

**EDIT 3**:
Entering

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

returned

> linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

and entering

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

returned

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0 B/1,512 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   (Reading database ... 413294 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
>   Removing all DKMS Modules
>   Done.
>   Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
>   Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
>   Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
>   Building only for 3.13.0-68-generic
>   Building for architecture x86_64
>   Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
>   modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
>   update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
>   Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
>   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic

(sudo modprobe wl also returned FATAL: Module wl not found).

**EDIT 4**:

Entering

> sudo apt-get install linux-generic

produced

> The following extra packages will be installed:
>     linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic
>     linux-image-generic
>   Suggested packages:
>     fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     linux-generic linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic
>     linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic linux-image-generic
>   0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 52.0 MB of archives.
>   After this operation, 194 MB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
>   Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic amd64 3.13.0-76.120 [15.2 MB]
>   Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic amd64 3.13.0-76.120 [36.8 MB]
>   Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-generic amd64 3.13.0.76.82 [2,250 B]
>   Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-generic amd64 3.13.0.76.82 [1,780 B]
>   Fetched 52.0 MB in 3s (16.3 MB/s)
>   Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic.
>   (Reading database ... 413294 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic_3.13.0-76.120_amd64.deb ...
>   Done.
>   Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic (3.13.0-76.120) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic.
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic_3.13.0-76.120_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic (3.13.0-76.120) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_3.13.0.76.82_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking linux-image-generic (3.13.0.76.82) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
>   Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_3.13.0.76.82_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking linux-generic (3.13.0.76.82) ...
>   Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic (3.13.0-76.120) ...
>   Running depmod.
>   update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
>   Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Generating grub configuration file ...
>   Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-66-generic
>   Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
>   Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
>   done
>   Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic (3.13.0-76.120) ...
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-76-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Generating grub configuration file ...
>   Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-76-generic
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-66-generic
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-66-generic
>   Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
>   Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
>   done
>   Setting up linux-image-generic (3.13.0.76.82) ...
>   Setting up linux-generic (3.13.0.76.82) ...

which looked promising, but upon reboot WiFi still fails. However, now

> sudo modprobe wl

produces

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-76-generic/modules.dep.bin'

if that's relevant.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: @chili555: Added at the bottom above.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`, then reboot and try again. But you need to connect to internet first. You have different versions of headers and image.

Comment: Now run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update kernel and headers first. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Reboot and run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: This finally worked, thanks! I'm posting from WiFi now. For future reference, do you have any idea how the header-image mismatch occurred? I remember going back and deleting old headers/images a couple of times in the past after my Boot ran out of memory, but that hasn't happened in a while, and I'm not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 2):

The correct driver for your device, *wl*, has gone missing. Let's try to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Please post any errors, warnings, etc.

We see this:

> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
>   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: See bottom of above for my response.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed now. Pilot6's answer actually got it working, but I'm guessing your answer started the fix, so I voted this up too.